# Cant pass UIImageView in UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to pass a `UIImageView` as a parameter through a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, e.g. `addTapGestureRecognizer(passedView: questionImage)` where `questionImage` is a `UIImageView`. Code like so:

```
    // MARK: Tap Gesture Recognizer

    func addTapGestureRecognizer(passedView: UIView) {
        let photoTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapPhoto(_:)))
        photoTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        passedView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        passedView.addGestureRecognizer(photoTapGestureRecognizer)

    }

    func didTapPhoto(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Did detect the tap")
        if let imageView = sender as? UIImageView {
            print("Is an image view")
        }

    }
```

When I tap the `UIImageView` it detects the tap and prints the first statement. However it will not cast `sender` into a `UIImageView` and print the second statement. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you ADDED THE gesture to view not the imageview

Comment: a UIImageView is a UIView. (A subclass of it)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `sender.view` in order to get which view is tapped

```
func didTapPhoto(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Did detect the tap")
    if (sender.view as? UIImageView) != nil {
        print("Is an image view")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let imageView = sender.view as? UIImageView {
        print("Is an image view")
    }
```